# Why does this jekyll template not work?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

### Short Version:

Why does the following code not produce an output when `navbox.next_article` is the string '2018-01-05-man-command'?!

```
{% capture np %} {{ site.posts | where:"post","navbox.next_article contains post.title" }} {% endcapture %}
The next post is {{ np.title }}
```

---

#### Details

My post `2018-01-05-man-command.md` has a YAML front matter:

```
---
layout : post
title : 'Man Command'
tags : [RHCSA, RHCSA_mod, Using Essential Tools, Man Command]
categories: [RHCSA]
navbox:
#  prev_article:
  next_article: 2018-01-05-understanding-globbing-and-wildcards
---
```

This is accessed by the `_includes/post.html` file through:

```
{% unless include.excerpt %}
  {{ post.content }}
  {% include navbox.html navbox=page.navbox %}    
{% endunless %}
```

This is used by the `_layout/post.html` which sets the layout for the post:

```
{% include post.html post=page link_title=false %}
```

My `navbox.html` contains:

```
{% assign navbox = include.navbox %}

{% capture np %} {{ site.posts | where:"post","navbox.next_article contains post.title" }} {% endcapture %}
The next post is {{ np.title }}
```

However, all I get when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` is:

> The next post is

Why does that line not work? I'm new to jekyll so it's possible I've made a blunder somewhere that's intuitive to most. Please tell me what I can fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `capture` tag only captures strings, not posts. See [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#capture) for more info.

I'm not convinced that a `where` filter supports the `contains` syntax you're using. See [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2787) for more info.

On top of that, `where` returns an array. You have to get the first item from that array.

You need to fix these issues. Use an `assign` instead of a `capture` to store a post. And change your `where` filter to not use the `contains` syntax, which isn't valid. (Unless it's been added since the issue I just linked.)

Here is how I've done it:

```
{% assign post = site.posts | where:"url", targetUrl | first %}
```